# adding a level in has many association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

I have a association in my rails application between States and hospitals.
A State has many hospitals and a hospital belongs to one state.
So,

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hospitals
end

class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

So, I have a state_id column in my hospitals table.
Now, due to some requirement, I need to add a level of hierarchy in this association ie. a new Model City. 
Such that,a state has many cities, and a city has many hospitals, so, a state has many hospitals.

My models now should like this -

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :hospitals, through: :cities
end

class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hospitals
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Will such a change in models work, if I want to run queries like `@state.hospitals`

Also, my application already has data populated for `State 1....n Hospitals` association using the `state_id` column. How do I go to add this model in between and keep the data sane ??

I'm new to rails and any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks.